# folding custom regions in IntelliJ idea (typeScript)

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea

In Visual Studio and Netbeans I am able to folding custom regions with line comments.

> -visual studio style:

`#region Description
      Your code goes here...
  #endregion`

> -netbeans style:

```
// <editor-fold desc="Description">
     Your code goes here...
// </editor-fold>
```

My question is, can I folding custom regions in intellij idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Go to **Code -> Surround With..** ( or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
- Select **region..endregion Comments**

Refer [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/) for more.

Comment: how can I do it for files with .feature extension?

Comment: @laechoppe it should be all right for any extension? Do you experience any problem?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne yep, it seems to be a not implemented thing yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-24080

Answer (score 4):

## Typescript

### [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

```
// #region NameOfRegion
   // * Your Code Here ...
// #endregion
```

### [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

```
// region NameOfRegion
   // * Your Code Here ...
// endregion
```

The difference is the '#' before '*region*'

Comment: I've been trying to find a solution for regions to work across visual studio and webstorm (inteliji). Is that even possible?